# How to add progress-indicator in status bar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, statusbar

I have developed an application for OS X. I am now building a status bar application. This application is related to wireless communication, hence I have to connect to a particular device. It is like the wifi status bar. I would like to have the message : "looking for networks" and then when the network is found it should then display the available networks. How do I obtain this?

I am relatively new to X-code and OS X so please try to be elaborate.

Thank you

Comment: I would be happy to elaborate for $50/hour. Otherwise, please get a basic understanding of your problem first. Have you taken a look at the `NSStatusItem` and `NSStatusBar` classes?

Comment: Post your code and show us what you have done so far.

Comment: You could also think about adding a window (and window controller) to your app, then use IB to put a progress indicator (or image view), textfield and combo box in the window.

Comment: @ElTomato I haven't coded anything in this context so far, all I have done is I have mutable array of available networks. This question is a general question, how would you make the transition between the "looking for networks" and "networks are available" and then list them?